# nltk on macOS Sierra

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, nltk, macos-sierra

I'm trying to install NLTK on Sierra with:

```
sudo pip install -U nltk
```

with this command, NLTK is installed in:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

But then, when I try to import NLTK with python, python doesn't find the module. I guess NLTK is installed in the wrong directory.
So I tried to move it using the bash and doing:

```
cd /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
cp -r nltk /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
```

and here another problem:

> Permission denied
>   cp: nltk: unable to copy extended attributes to /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk: Permission denied
>   cp: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/**init**.py: No such file or directory...

I'll appreciate a lot any suggestion! I didn't have any problem in installing NLTK on my old mac (os 10.9.5) with the `sudo` command.

Thank you!

Comment: I solved the problem adding sudo before: 

cp -r nltk /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages  Now nltk works! I hope this post will be helpful to someone else!

Comment: Create a virtualenv, see http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/. Otherwise try `pip install --user nltk`

Comment: thank you for the reply! What is the difference between pip install -U nltk and pip install --user nltk?

Comment: `-U` is upgrade. `--user` is installing in the user environment. See https://ehmatthes.github.io/pcc/chapter_12/installing_pip.html or `man pip`.

Comment: You can answer your own question and mark it as accepted. This will be more likely to help future visitors than a comment!

Answer (score 0):

Yup, using the `sudo` command before the `cd` and `cp` should grant you permission to change the file directory.